# How to start an smsSenderactivty in Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, sms

I am receiving SMS, through Broadcast receiver and poping a toast about SMS, then in other class I had smsSenderActivity? I have to call that Activity when I click Ok on toast that poped, when SMS comes? How do I call smssender Activity?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I think [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) is what you are looking for.

Good luck
Tom